# Display only 1 value from Controller List JSP

Tags: html, jsp, model-view-controller, controller

Currently I am rendering multiple values from controller list of objects to jsp using

```
<tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Date</td>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${usersInfo}" var="user">
   <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.address}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${user.date}"/></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

But is it possible to show only one record instead of using "for" because I know date value is going to be the same for all. For ex:

```
 <h1> Date : <${usersInfo.date}></h1>
```

Comment: usersInfo[0].date

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of the first record in any variable and show the same every time.
Like date d= list.get(0).getDate();
and display the value of d every time not user.date.